# Popups' buttons on arcgis JS map doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I want to display with scatters some items on a arcgis js map. And I want to create popup for each point. To do it I use the following js code:

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script>
<script>
    require([
      "esri/config",
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",

      ], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) {
      esriConfig.apiKey = "MyApiKey";

      const map = new Map({
          basemap: "arcgis-light-gray" // Basemap layer service
      });

      const view = new MapView({
          map: map,
          center: [0, 20.0], // Longitude, latitude
          zoom: 1, // Zoom level
          container: "digital-win-map", // Div element
          constraints: {
                minZoom: 1
            },
      });

      const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      map.add(graphicsLayer);

      for(let item of {{items|safe}}){
        if (item.LOCALISATION){
            const point = { //Create a point
                type: "point",
                latitude: item.LOCALISATION.split(", ")[0],
                longitude: item.LOCALISATION.split(", ")[1],
            };

            const simpleMarkerSymbol = {
                type: "simple-marker",
                color: [226, 119, 40],  // Orange
                outline: {
                    color: [255, 255, 255], // White
                    width: 1
                }
            };

            const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                geometry: point,
                symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol,
                popupTemplate: {
                    title: `${item.Name} ${item.Date}`, // Data attribute names
                    content: `${item.content}`
                  }
            });
            graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
        }
      };
  });
</script>
```

When I click on the certain point I see the popup with corresponded information but some popups' buttons, such as close-button, doesn't work. What is my error?